# Why is this async function returning empty on the first try, but then it returns everything?

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to insert data to my db, and the query is inside a map loop, so i'm using an async function to wait for the loop to end, and store all the results in my variable "practicasAgregadas".

This is how i call the function:

```js
insertarPracticas(turno_id, req.body.lista_codigos_practicas, queryInsertarPracticas)
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({
      "Practicas Agregadas": result
    })
  })
```

This is the function:

```js
async function insertarPracticas(turno_id, req, queryInsertarPracticas) {
  const res = await Promise.all(req.map(r => {
    connection.query(
      queryInsertarPracticas, [turno_id, r], (error2, row2) => {
        if (error2) {
          console.log("Error al insertar turno detalle (prácticas): " + r + " " + error2);
          practicasNoAgregadas += r + "-";
        } else {
          console.log("Turnos detalle agregados " + r);
          practicasAgregadas += r + "-";
          console.log("practicas " + practicasAgregadas);
        }
      });
    return practicasAgregadas;
  })
  )

  console.log("en async " + res[0]);
  return res;
}
```

On the first try, it returns empty:

[image]

This is the console:

[image]

And on the second try, it does return, but it repeats 3 times:

[image]

And the console:

[image]

Comment: You are attempting mix plain asynchronous callbacks with promises.  You cannot do that as `Promise.all()` requires that you pass it promises that resolve when your asynchronous operation completes, but your `async` function does not do that because `connection.query()` does not return a promise.

Comment: `(error2, row2) =>`  this is a callback, you need to promisify it..  You might find that `connection.query` will return a promise if the callback is not supplied, a lot of libs seem to be doing this now.  So -> `const [turno_id, r] = await connection.query()`, you can also use `try / catch` for your error logic.  Note you will then need -> `req.map(async r.....` to do the await.

Comment: @jfriend00 and what's the correct way to do it? how can i make it return a promise?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the promise interface for your database instead of the callback interface.  Then `connection.query()` will return a promise.  You don't say what database you're using, but if it's mysql, then there is a mysql module on NPM that supports promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern JS libs that use async functions will return a promise, but will often not return a promise if the callback is supplied.

So assuming connection.query does return a promise, then the code below should do what your after..

```
async function insertarPracticas(turno_id, req, queryInsertarPracticas) {
    const res = await Promise.all(
        req.map(async (r) => {
            try {
                const row2 = await connection.query(queryInsertarPracticas, [
                    turno_id, r
                ]);
                console.log("Turnos detalle agregados " + r);
                practicasAgregadas += r + "-";
                console.log("practicas " + practicasAgregadas);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(
                    "Error al insertar turno detalle (prácticas): " +
                        r + " " + error2
                );
                practicasNoAgregadas += r + "-";
            }
            return practicasAgregadas;
        })
    );

    console.log("en async " + res[0]);
    return res;
}
```

Remember, don't use a callback, or that could indicate to the lib that your not wanting a promise returning.

If for some reason the lib has not been updated for a long while, you will need to promisify the query..

In node, there is a nice utility called promisify https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal that will make this bit easier.

eg.

```
const conQuery = util.promisify(connection.query);
const row2 = await conQuery(queryInsertarPracticas....
```

If the callback is not in the form `(error, result)` you would need to use a Promise constructor.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise , but looking at your code `(error2, row2) =>` that shouldn't be required.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get the actual mysql module that supports promises directly so you're not having to do this manual promisification everywhere?

Comment: Also, where does the variable `practicasAgregadas` come from?  Because you're adding onto it in an indeterminate order since all these queries will run in parallel and complete in random order.

Comment: Im sorry i couldnt reply earlier, this worked! Thank you, im gonna have to learn more about promises and callbacks

Comment: @jfriend00  Yes, if there is a lib that already uses promises that's certainly an option too.  Saying that, it's not something I always do, I remember years ago using `request`, and then there was a promise version `request-promise`, that added a fair chunk of dependencies, when a 1 liner promisify would work.  And, yes, if order is important that's something you need to be aware of with `Promise.all`, but with the OP currently doing `+= r + "-";` , order of course is not important here.

Comment: @Keith can i ask you another question? when you do: const row2 = await connection.query(...) , should row2 return with the results of a select statement from my query? because when i console log it, it brings a lot of info but nothing to do with the result of the query

Comment: @le0nicolas  If it's a promise yes, if you are indeed just using npm `mysql`, from looking at the repo it doesn't have any support for promises, so like @jfriend00 says you might want to use a repo that has it built in, eg.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql  or use  `util.promisify` etc.

Comment: @Keith im trying to use mysql2/promise, but it crashes the server lol (i had to wrap everything inside a main function, but then it won't find the /post rout).. what i get on the console.log() is the same that happened here: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1002

Im gonna try using util.promisify

Comment: @Keith I GOT IT!!! Thank you so much, all i had to do was const query = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection); and implement your code. Thanks!!!!